# Не могу понять как подключить jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Знаю, что можно подключить jquery на сайт, но можно ли работать с ним из консоли(например, подключить его из консоли и кликнуть по элементу)?

Answer (score 3):

Подключить:

```
let jqScript = document.createElement('script');
jqScript.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js';
document.body.appendChild(jqScript);
let jQ = $.noConflict(true);
```

*(просто скопируйте код в консоль браузера, и нажмите Enter)*
Последняя строка восстанавливает символ $, если уже использовался на странице.

---

Кликнуть по элементу:

```
jQ('селектор_элемента').trigger('click'); // тут я не уверен - сам не использую jQuery
```

Comment: А как подключить на странице с https?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду URL? (схема была http://). Если да - я это исправил. Как и путь ссылки - теперь она указывает на актуальную в данный момент версию jQuery. А если я неправильно понял вопрос в комментарии, поясните пожалуйста.

Comment: В консоли лучше не использовать `$`

Comment: @vp_arth, если есть дополнения или поправки к ответу - прошу, не стесняйтесь.